# Package installation doubt

Tags: salesforce-id

I created a package in a devloper login by selecting app.the created package contains objects.

how to install in another developer login.

If I install the package the objects will be present in new dev login right.wot abt data present in that object. will that also exists.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you install the package the subscriber org all components in the package will be installed in that org.

NO Data will be included in the package.